# SQL return list of ntext and convert it to XML

Tags: sql, xml

I have a query that will return and a list of ntext, and in these ntext they contain XML value.
my question is how to convert each of ntext to xml and do logic with it

Query:

```
select a.content 
from dbo.content as a
inner join dbo.xml_collection_tbl as b on a.xml_fg_id = b.xml_collection_id
where a.inherit_from='val1' and b.collection_title='val2' and a.content_table= 'val3'
```

result:
[image]

what I want to do here is to check rather the Query returns contain the value that I looking for. lets say the page title = "hello World"

I tried below.But it returns many empty rows and with one correct row

```
select cast(a.content_html as xml).query('(//root[pagetitle/text()="AAA"])') content_html1
from dbo.content as a
inner join dbo.xml_collection_tbl as b on a.xml_fg_id = b.xml_collection_id
where a.inherit_from='val1' and b.collection_title='val2' and a.content_table= 'val3'
```

[image]

expected result is: return only one row where it's not empty (row 54)

Comment: Cast the column as XML and apply XML methods https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/xml-data-type-methods

Comment: Hi Serg thanks for the asnwer but i try select @xmlData = CAST(a.content_html  AS XML).query('(//root[pagetitle/text()="hello World"])'), but return many empty result

Comment: Edit  the question and provide sample data and  expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: `NTEXT`, `TEXT` and `IMAGE` are deprecated for centuries and will not be supported in future versions! Get rid of this type as soon as possible!

SQL-Server does not store the XML as the text you see, but as a hierarchically stuctured tree. This makes the handling of an XML astonishingly fast (**no parsing on string level!**). Your approach has to parse each and every XML over and over, which is a **very expensive operation!** Change your XML's storage to the native XML type and you will be very happy with the new performance!

If you have to stick with this, you can try as such:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY, YourXML NTEXT);
INSERT INTO @t VALUES('<root><pagetitle>111</pagetitle></root>')
                    ,('<root><pagetitle>aaa</pagetitle></root>')
                    ,('<root><pagetitle>222</pagetitle></root>')
SELECT A.CastedXML
      ,B.pt.query('.')
FROM @t AS t
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CAST(YourXML AS XML) AS CastedXML) AS A
CROSS APPLY A.CastedXML.nodes('/root/pagetitle[text()="aaa"]') AS B(pt);
```

Answer (score 1):

Demo of XQuery expression https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/xquery-language-reference-sql-server to filter data

```
with sd as (
    select cast(content_html as xml) as col
    from (
        values 
        ('<root><pagetitle>FFF</pagetitle></root>')
        ,('<root><pagetitle>AAA</pagetitle></root>')
    ) as a(content_html)
)
select t.n.value('.[1]', 'varchar(100)') as content_html1
from sd
cross apply col.nodes('root/pagetitle[text()="AAA"]') t(n)
```